# Woocommerce Get all product variations by category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product-variations

I need to get all Woocommerce product variations that belongs to selected category. I tried to query that this way:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
    'post_status'   => array( 'private', 'publish' ),           
    'tax_query'     => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => $selected_category_id
    )   
);

$variations = get_posts( $args );
```

but "tax_query" part seems to be ignored and no matter what will be provided inside, it does not affect the query.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

[**Tax Query Docs**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

> Important Note: tax_query takes an **array** of tax query arguments arrays
>   (**it takes an array of arrays**). This construct allows you to query
>   multiple taxonomies by using the relation parameter in the first
>   (outer) array to describe the boolean relationship between the
>   taxonomy arrays.

I suggest you to use **new WP_QUERY()** instead **get_posts()** using WP_QUERY you can see query ran against your arguments via **`var_dump($variations->request);`**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product_variation',
    'post_status' => array('private', 'publish'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $selected_category_id
        )
    )
);

$variations = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($variations->request); // dump SQL query
```

Comment: Nope, I have tried this way at first, but it gives me empty result, no matter which category I select.

Comment: Product categories are assigned to parent variable product, not product_variations themselves

Answer (score -1):

```
            function get_products_from_category_by_id( $category ) {
                $products = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type'   => 'product',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'fields'      => 'ids',
                    'tax_query'   => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field'    => 'term_id',
                        'terms'    => $category,
                    )
                    ),
                ));
                return $products->posts;
            }
            
            $loop = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type'       => 'product_variation',
                'post_status'     => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page'  => -1,
                'post_parent__in' => get_products_from_category_by_id(99),
                'meta_query'      => array(
                'relation'    => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key'     => '_stock',
                        'value'   => 0,
                        'compare' => '>'
                    ),
                )
            ));
```